Does the use of an iterator imply a heap object?
Does the creation of an object of type IEnumerable<T> (such as the numbers object of type IEnumerable<int> in the below code example) imply the creation of an object on the heap that has finally to be garbage-collected?
Consider for example the following iterator as described in this blog post
IEnumerable<int> GetOneTwoThree() {
  yield return 1;
  yield return 2;
  yield return 3;
}

and then its usage with
var numbers = GetOneTwoThree();

foreach (var number in numbers) {
  Console.WriteLine(number);
}


The state of the method (where the last executed yield was) needs to be stored somewhere. And it's certainly not on the stack

yield (and foreach) are "just" syntax sugar, I recommend taking a look at what's actually being compiled with a tool like sharplab to gain a deeper understanding.

why do you care? What problem do you actually try to solve by answering this? Or is this rather academic interest?

@MakePeaceGreatAgain In the end it is about performance. In certain parts of our code (parts that are executed many times) we avoid heap allocations, because we have found that the GC slows down our app, in particular in the context of multithreading.

well, you certainly don't allocate billions of iterators, do you? So the difference - if any at all - is probably negligable. However only you can measure.

^^ and a benchmark could show the effects if you absolutely need to know (or prove to superiors).

Right, we should do a benchmark. Nevertheless, I am still interested in the answer.

I think you got the answer in the very first comment, didn't you?

In other words: while it's possible to iterate allocation-free, using IEnumerable<T> is most unlikely to be.

@Fildor you poet, nice rhyme.

@Raildex needing state doesn't necessitate heap allocation, so the question is very valid (sharplab example follows); as an implementation detail it is the case that the compiler doesn't currently support writing custom iterators as struct when using yield return

https://sharplab.io/#v2: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

@MakePeaceGreatAgain Wasn't intentional, though I have to admit.


imply the creation of an object on the heap that has finally to be garbage-collected?

Short answer: Yes, in this case
Apart from anything else: the moment you're implementing IEnumerable<T>, that means your iterator is typed as IEnumerator<T>, so even if it was actually being implemented in a value-type: it will be boxed (thus: a heap allocation) when typed as the interface.

Longer answer: it is possible to write hand written iterators that use struct (or even ref struct), which then may be used without any heap allocation - as long as the type is used explicitly rather than via the IEnumerable<T>/IEnumerator<T> interfaces - List<T> is an example of this, with a custom value-type iterator. However, that precludes the use of yield return - it must be hand written. Fortunately foreach is duck-typed, so can make efficient use of such custom iterators (when the GetEnumerator() method returns something bespoke that has the required features).

Couldn't a boxed IEnumerator<T> be stackalloced?

@OlivierJacot-Descombes I am not aware of any scenario where the runtime and/or JIT uses the stack for boxing operations (and the compiler certainly doesn't), and the escape analysis required for that would be significant - happy to be corrected, though

@OlivierJacot-Descombes See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/11192 and https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/103361 it's coming but it's a huge amount of work.
